# Firestore "startAt" keeps bringing the same data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a **pagination** with firestore, the problem is that even if I change the **startAt** it still brings the same results.

**An example of my problem**

```
const snaps = await db.collection('blogs').
              .orderBy('createdAt')
              .startAt(0)
              .limit(5).get();

const snaps2 = await db.collection('blogs').
              .orderBy('createdAt')
              .startAt(5)
              .limit(5).get();
let billList = [] 
let billList2 = []

snaps.forEach(x => billList.push(x.data()) ) 
snaps2.forEach(x => billList.push(x.data()) ) 

console.log(billList)
console.log(billList2)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The pagination API doesn't work the way you are expecting.  It [startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startat) doesn't accept an integer offset.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it requires either:

- A DocumentReference of the document to start at
- A array of field values relative to the order of the query (themselves also typically taken from documents

The paging API doesn't work with offsets at all.  You can't skip ahead by N documents at a time.  What you have to do is read N documents, then read the next N documents, and so on.  I suggest reading the [documentation on pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) for specific examples.  Note that the first example is not requesting an offset of 1000000 - it's actually asking to start with cities at or above a population field value of 1000000.